# Error of the Numerov Method

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The Numerov method is an iterative algorithm for solving second order differential equations. A full derivation is here on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov's_method. I am interested in the derivation of the error bound of this algorithm (which is supposedly $O(n^4)$). I understand how in the derivation on this Wikipedia page that we achieve error of $O(n^5)$, but then it concludes that "It follows that the order of convergence (assuming stability) is 4." Could someone explain how we went from an error of order 5 to error of order 4?

I am interested for the following reason. Suppose we have two values for the numerov method N(n) and N(2n) for step size $n$. Then I desire to determine constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$\alpha N(2n) + \beta N(n)$$
reduces the overall error of the result. Any help and advice would bemuch appreciated!

Comment: I haven't looked into details of this particular method, but a rule of thumb in numerical analysis of ODEs is that the local error is $O(h^{k+1})$ and the global error is $O(h^k)$. That's because you make $O(1/h)$ steps and make an error of $O(h^{k+1})$ at each, for a total of $O(h^k)$.

Comment: Also, what you are doing is of course Richardson extrapolation, and it uses the global order, not the local order.

Comment: By the way, in view of the second Dahlquist barrier, you should be very careful using this method: it may be good for certain problems, but it is *not* A-stable, so it will likely perform very poorly in certain problems.